# Need to change customer account side tabs layout Vertical Layout to horizontal on top.Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, css, magento2.3.1, html

I need to change the My Account section side tabs layout (Vertical to Horizontal) and wanted to add on top before the My Videos Label.

[image]

Please Help me to change this layout.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below CSS

```
.customer-account-index .columns {
    display: flex;
}
```

Change parent class according to your need.